# ¿Cómo se deben escribir en español las palabras que se escriben acortadas para simular el habla?

Tags: coloquialismos, ortografía, contracciones

Aquí en Andalucía somos muy de comernos la mitad de las palabras, con ejemplos como "y to pa na" (y todo para nada). Sin embargo, siempre he tenido la duda de cómo reflejar esto en la expresión escrita cuando quiero simular que, en un diálogo, el que habla tiene ese acento (al estilo de los cómics de [Ivà](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iv%C3%A0), que sabían reflejar perfectamente el peculiar estilo de habla de cada personaje).

A lo largo del tiempo he usado varias opciones:

> - **Y to pa na**
> - **Y *to pa na*** (nótense las cursivas para enfatizar las palabras acortadas)
> - **Y "to pa na"** (variante de la anterior, con comillas)
> - **Y tó pá ná** (tildes para enfatizar cada palabra acortada)
> - **Y to' pa' na'** (con apóstrofos al estilo inglés para indicar la ausencia del resto de la palabra)

¿Existe algún tipo de regla que se deba aplicar en estas situaciones? ¿Cuál sería la opción correcta?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dado que se trata de apócopes, parece que lo correcto sería decir:

> **Y to pa na**.

Según la [Ortografía de la RAE 2010](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Ortograf%C3%ADa-%20RAE%202010-Signos%20auxiliares.htm), en su sección de **apóstrofo**:

> Se empleaba para indicar la omisión o elisión de alguna vocal: *d’aquel*. Recientemente, se ha restablecido en algunas reimpresiones de textos antiguos. Su utilización se limita a usos filológicos o literarios.
>
> Se utiliza también para reflejar en la escritura la supresión de sonidos que se produce en la pronunciación de palabras sucesivas en la lengua oral: *¡Para el carro o m’acatarro!* Cuando cae la vocal final de la primera palabra y la segunda empieza por hache, esta debe conservarse: *Vamos pa l’Habana*.
>
> **El apóstrofo no debe utilizarse para marcar ni las apócopes ni las aféresis de una voz que se producen con independencia de la palabra que les siga: *pa* por *para*; *na* por *nada*; *ña* por *doña*.**

Recordemos que [**aféresis**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0wyYhT6) es *«Supresión de algún sonido al principio de un vocablo, como en norabuena por enhorabuena»* y [**apócope**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3DQrjNM) *«Supresión de algún sonido al final de un vocablo, como en primer por primero»*. Este es el caso que nos presentas, al utilizar las apócopes *to* por *todo*, *pa* por *para* y *na* por *nada*.

De todos modos, detecto cierta ambigüedad para los casos de *«supresión de sonidos que se produce en la pronunciación de palabras sucesivas en la lengua oral»*, pues considero que estos pueden ser apócopes también: ¿Deberíamos decir *pa Ana* o *p'Ana* para mostrar la contracción de *para Ana*?  Seguramente *p'Ana*.

---

Nótese que según el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas, en su versión web de 2005, lo correcto sería usar el apóstrofo y decir *Y to' pa' na'*.

> [**apóstrofo**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=wV8heEHVFD64FHx2Ng). Signo ortográfico auxiliar en forma de coma alta (’), que apenas se usa en el español actual.
>
> 1. Como usos propios de la lengua española, se distinguen principalmente dos:
>
> b) **Para reflejar, en la escritura, la supresión de sonidos que se produce en ciertos niveles de la lengua oral**. Aparece con frecuencia en textos literarios cuando el autor desea reproducir el habla de personajes de escasa cultura: *«Sacúdete el vestidito, m’ija, pa’que se nos salga el mal agüero»* (Hayen Calle [Méx. 1993]).

Comment: Qué curioso, era la opción que menos me imaginaba. Por cierto, que eso de "personajes de escasa cultura" es algo que se le puede discutir "muy mucho" a la RAE. :)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ¡ya te digo! Como para decirles "si me queréis, irse". Pues lo curioso es que otra fuente dice algo contrario: [uso del apóstrofo](http://udep.edu.pe/castellanoactual/duda-resuelta-uso-del-apostrofo/) _Según se recoge en la última ortografía académica no debe utilizarse el apóstrofo para marcar la supresión de sonidos finales, como sucede con el acortamiento “na” de “nada”, o iniciales, como en el acortamiento de “ña” de “doña”, ni mucho menos de sonidos interiores (creío en lugar de “creído”)_.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo en [Ortografía - RAE 2010](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Ortograf%C3%ADa-%20RAE%202010-Signos%20auxiliares.htm) hablan de _El apóstrofo no debe utilizarse para marcar ni las apócopes ni las aféresis de una voz que se producen con independencia de la palabra que les siga: pa por para; na por nada; ña por doña_. Vale, voy a buscar más porque la referencia del DPD no sé de cuándo es.

Comment: Por eso mismo creo que la respuesta puede tener algo más de miga. El DPD es de 2005, anterior a la última ortografía. Hemos tenido esta discusión en varias preguntas, sobre cuál tiene más validez, si el DPD o la última versión de la ortografía.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo acabo de verlo en la web del DPD. Esta es una nota importante, por lo que invalida mi respuesta. La editaré para reflejar todo esto. Qué curioso, por cierto, que cambiara el criterio en apenas cinco años.