# ¿Cuál es el significado de «Yo estoy pa lo mío»?

Tags: coloquialismos, letras-de-canciones

He escuchado en [esta canción](https://youtu.be/GdORLw_2oFM?t=47s), por una cantante estadounidense de linaje dominicano, y [esta canción](https://youtu.be/9DHIaDYJey0), por un cantante cubano, la letra

> Yo estoy pa lo mío

y me pregunto qué quiere decir. Entiendo que *pa’* es *para*, pero además de eso no entiendo el significado.

¿Tal vez quiere decir algo como, «Me concentro en los asuntos míos»?

Comment: ¿De dónde son los cantantes? Nótese por cierto que se recomienda escribir _Estoy pa lo mío_, según lo que comentamos en [¿Cómo se deben escribir en español las palabras que se escriben acortadas para simular el habla?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19504/1674)

Comment: @fedorqui Lo corregí, y de linaje dominicano y de Cuba (que también añadí a la publicación)

Comment: También podría ser: "Yo cuido de mis asuntos"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correcto, `Yo estoy pa' lo mío` se puede aceptar como `Me concentro en mis asuntos`, aunque generalmente se usa para resaltar que `no me interesa otra cosa`.

Ampliación:

Cuba y Dominicana son muy cercanos lingüísticamente, en ambos países la frase `estoy pa' lo mío/estoy para lo mío` implícitamente expresa que una la persona no pierde el enfoque de sus asuntos personales por otras cosas a las que da menos o ninguna importancia.

El antónimo de frase sería el "cubanismo" `ponte pa' lo tuyo/ponte para lo tuyo`, que se interpreta como `ocúpate de tus asuntos`, y que implícitamente expresa `no te metas en los asuntos de otros` es también muy común y se puede encontrar en algunas letras de canciones de la región así como en el argot popular.

Comment: Si quisieras incluir evidencias que apoyen las dos interpretations, yo podrías poner la tilde verde

Comment: No he encontrado fuentes académicas que expliquen la interpretación de esta frase, soy cubano, vivo en Cuba y esta respuesta se basa en mi experiencia personal.

Comment: Qué interesante es ese tercer párrafo

Answer (score 0):

Es algo egocentrista creo la frase pero aún así estas en lo correcto, da a entender que se preocupa solo o más por si mismo.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido al sitio, Paul! Aunque tu comentario parece correcto, aquí nos encantan las respuestas largas y extensas que explican cuantos más detalles mejor. Por ejemplo, ¿en qué países se usa esa frase? ¿Podrías darnos más ejemplos de uso? ¿Es tal vez demasiado coloquial, o se usa en ámbitos más formales? Consulta la sección [amswer] si necesitas más ayuda (o simplemente pídela), y esperamos ver más contribuciones tuyas por aquí.

Comment: Gracias!, lo tendré en cuenta :).

Comment: Saludos desde Perú!.