# ¿Cómo escribir locuciones verbales en diálogos y literatura?

Tags: locuciones, literatura

Me parece que en la escritura narrativa se deben evitar las locuciones verbales precisamente porque la "locución" no existe.

Sin embargo en los diálogos creo que se debería "evitar" evitarlas, precisamente porque las personas hablan con locuciones verbales y le dan veracidad y autenticidad a los diálogos.

Un caso muy específico es el de "a lo mejor", que suele pronunciarse como una sola palabra como sinónimo de "tal vez":

> "alomejor / alamejor"

Siendo que se trata de un diálogo y esta locución es difícil de interpretar cuando lees las tres palabras por separado. Creo que se debería escribir en una sola palabra para mantener la veracidad del diálogo y aunque por otro lado es una falta ortográfica, al hablar de diálogos tenemos que identificar algo claro "la gente no habla como escribe".

Entonces, ¿cuál es la manera correcta de abordar estos casos?

¿Poner la locución en negritas, evitarla, o simplemente escribirla sin ninguna anotación?

Comment: No veo como "a lo mejor" se pronuncia como una sola palabra. No es que uno haga pausas entre las palabras pero así se pronuncia todo en cualquier lenguaje, las palabras se entremezclan, pero no es que dejen de ser palabras independientes. Creo que aquí tenemos una confusión respecto a lo que es una locución verbal. [Ver aquí ejemplos de locuciones verbales](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Locuci%C3%B3n_verbal)

Comment: Hacer pausas para pronunciar *a lo mejor* no tiene ningún sentido; eso haría que uno suene como robot. Además, y como sucede con todos los idiomas, siempre está presente el uso del discurso o diálogo conectado, en donde pegamos las palabras para dar fluidez.

Comment: @Ustanak asi es, e incluso intercambiamos letras, por ejemplo al pronunciar "en paz" pronunciamos "empaz"

Comment: *A lo mejor* se pronunciará siempre como una sola palabra tónica (a menos que sea una pronunciación pausada), debido a que se trata de dos palabras átonas y una tónica.  Toda palabra átona se pronuncia conjuntamente con la próxima palabra tónica.

Comment: No entiendo eso de no usar locuciones verbales en narrativa, ni tampoco esa afirmación de «la "locución" no existe».

Comment: una locución es una manera de hablar, en la "narración" raramente se emplea esto a menos que se quiera darle una personalidad al narrador, regionalismos y locuciones suelen (y deberian) ser evitados, sobre todo con narradores omnipresentes.

Comment: De los comentarios veo que la premisa de que "alomejor" es una locución verbal no es cierta y que además es falso que se pronuncie como una sola palabra por lo que como está escrita la pregunta no puede responderse.

Comment: Como dice el perfil de Mike si estoy en este SE es para aprender y de todo se aprende. Según este video "a lo mejor" sería una _locución **adverbial**_  Recomiendo vean este video y aunque no es la respuesta a la pregunta es muy educativo y explica con _lujo de detalles_ **[las diferencias entre locuciones verbales y perífrasis](https://www.unprofesor.com/lengua-espanola/diferencia-entre-una-locucion-verbal-y-una-perifrasis-verbal-289.html#tehagustado)**

Comment: No es exactamente el mismo, pero esto puede ser de interés: [¿Cómo se deben escribir en español las palabras que se escriben acortadas para simular el habla?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19504/c%C3%B3mo-se-deben-escribir-en-espa%C3%B1ol-las-palabras-que-se-escriben-acortadas-para-s)

Comment: Un autor puede hacer lo que le de la gana. O hace lo que le dice "su jefe" (productor, editor, etc.). No hay reglas. Todo depende de la creatividad y objetivo del autor. Los guiones son leídos por actores y los libros por lectores....el autor sabré que hacer. Así de claro (así declaro)....

Comment: Aconsejo que se lea: Carta a un joven escritor de Arturo Pérez-Riverte https://www.zendalibros.com/carta-joven-escritor/

Comment: correción: sabrá

Comment: En términos de pronunciación, es cierto que el español lleva esa manera de pronunciar una palabra casi juntada con otra hasta acabar la oración. En la escritura damos pausas por reconocer que cada palabra es una palabra por cuenta separada. Esto promueve la facilidad de la lectura que prosigue a la lengua hablada. Pero, en términos de prestar un énfasis en la forma particular de hablar de algún personaje en una historia, digamos, se vale demostrar esos modismos del hablar en la misma escritura. No hay regla que diga lo contrario aunque los patrones comunes sean otros.

Answer (score 1):

Inicialmente estaba decidido a escribir solamente un comentario pero quizá sea prudente extenderse un poco (en este caso) en atención al deseo de aprender del que pregunta.

Primero que nada, la pregunta se hace confusa cuando haces uso del término **locución verbal**. Creo una manera de replantear tu pregunta sería ¿Cómo se escriben las **locuciones** que son acortadas para simular el habla? En lo general, tu pregunta se discute [aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19504/c%C3%B3mo-se-deben-escribir-en-espa%C3%B1ol-las-palabras-que-se-escriben-acortadas-para-s). En el caso específico de **locuciones** te invito a seguir leyendo.

Para aclarar el concepto, podemos decir que una **locución** (así sola) es cualquier combinación de palabras que tienen un significado distinto a la de las partes que la conforman. Como tales, las palabras no pierden su individualidad. Ejemplos de oraciones que contienen locuciones son:

> Andaba **como loco** buscando un hotel
>   **A lo mejor** vamos en enero
>   **A lo mucho** nos quedaremos cinco días
>   Espero que no nos **echen a la calle**
>   Pásele **a lo barrido**

Ahora bien, cuando dices **locuciones verbales** estas hablando de un tipo especial de locución que funciona como verbo.

> Te **voy a echar de menos**
>   Cando la vio se **echó a correr**
>   El autor **dio a conocer** su libro

Finalmente, las entre las locuciones que son propensas a ser acortadas tenemos a las **locuciones adverbiales**.

> La película estuvo **para llorar** - *La peli estuvo **pa llorar***
>   No sirves **para nada** - *No sirves **pa ná***

Tanto la forma completa como la forma acortada son usadas de manera coloquial pero la única razón que yo tendría para escribirlas de manera acortada es para citar textualmente a un hablante.

Sin embargo, yo evitaría abusar de este recurso debido a que un escrito extenso que incluya palabras acortadas podría ser muy difícil de leer fuera del contexto cultural donde se genera.

Ejemplos literarios:

- En la novela de **Pedro Páramo** de Juan Rulfo. A pesar de que la historia tiene lugar en un ambiente provincial, el autor evita tajantemente el uso de palabras acortadas.
- Para dar voz a Cándido Castro, indio tzotzil de la novela **La Rebelión de los Colgados**, Bruno Traven no utiliza palabras acortadas.
- El mismo Miguel de Cervantes al darle voz a Sancho Panza, uno de los villanos mas famosos, no lo cita con palabras acortadas.

En conclusión, la mejor manera de escribir las voces acortadas es no hacerlo. Es mejor escribir las palabras completas.