# ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de escribir un error ortográfico adrede?

Tags: ortografía

Me refiero a que, en un texto relativamente formal, como un relato, tengas que escribir una palabra de manera incorrecta o bien para hacer referencia a ese error o por que forme parte de una expresión común. Pero dejando claro que sabes que la expresión es incorrecta, aunque la hayas usado.
Pongo tres ejemplos:

> A Laura le encantaba que los habitantes de su pueblo natal hablasen comiéndose las sílabas de las palabras. Casi podía oír en su cabeza la voz de su abuela diciéndole: **Ven pa ca niña**.

> Juan entró en el bar de siempre, pidió una cerveza y la tapa por excelencia de los **cuñaos**: Unas patatas bravas.

> En algunos lugares del mundo es común que las personas confundan el sonido de la C y la Z con el de la S, por lo que, en estos lugares es fácil encontrar **sapaterías**.

¿Cuál sería la manera correcta de escribir "pa ca", "cuñaos" o "sapaterías"? ¿Usando cursiva? ¿Comillas? ¿Simplemente escribiéndolo como cualquier otra palabra?

Comment: yo he visto lo siguiente escrito en varios libros pa' ca'. 'cuñaos', pero sapaterías lo tomaría no como un error del habla sino de la escritura. Cecear y Sesear están reconocidos como errores comunes del habla

Comment: Si, lo de poner una comilla simple al final para indicar que te has comido una silaba también lo he visto pero no sé si es correcto ponerlo así o habría que usar cursiva, por ejemplo. Lo mismo pasa con sapatería. ¿Como lo escribes para dar a entender que una persona ha cometido un error al rotular su negocio y no tú al escribir el texto?

Comment: Relacionada: _[¿Cómo se deben escribir en español las palabras que se escriben acortadas para simular el habla?_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19504/12637)

Comment: Si estás ecribiiendo literatura, no hay manera correcta. Eres tú el autor.

Comment: Relacionado: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/24785/112436

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si estás citando una fuente donde la palabra está escrita de manera incorrecta, se puede usar *[sic]* [como indica @mdewey](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32867/24236).

Si el texto es una producción literaria tuya, pienso que lo más apropiado es usar *cursiva*. En su [*Cursiva y redonda. Guía de estilo*](https://www.fundeu.es/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CursivasGuiaFundeu.pdf), Fundéu dice (negritas mías):

> Las principales funciones de la cursiva son de énfasis y para señalarle al lector que un sintagma o una palabra común puede resultarle ajena por ser un neologismo, **formar parte de una jerga o argot, adoptar una forma incorrecta o funcionar como metalenguaje**, es decir, no formar parte del discurso con el sentido propio de las palabras.

Los casos en negrita incluyen la gran mayoría de las razones por las que querrías escribir una palabra de manera incorrecta.

Answer (score 3):

Se puede poner (*sic*) despues de la palabra

Del [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/sic?m=form)

> sic
>   Del lat. sic 'así'.
>
> 1. adv. U. en impresos y manuscritos españoles, por lo general entre paréntesis, para dar a entender que una palabra o frase empleada en ellos, y que pudiera parecer inexacta, es textual.

Segun [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic) se usan cochetes y no paréntesis

Comment: Buena opción, pero creo que solo es válida cuando estás citando un texto y en este aparece un error, para dejar claro que el error está en el original y no en la reproducción. Si no estás citando otro texto, como parece ser el caso a juzgar por los ejemplos de la pregunta, no es válido el "sic".

Comment: @Charlie vamos a ver lo que dice BraveOtter

Comment: @mdewey En este caso me refería a un texto escrito por mi, no a una cita. Pero aun asi gracias ya que no lo conocía.